The doubt about the mechanism forcibly refreshing status with the yum repolist
I have noticed that there would be an additional "refreshing status" process every time running with the yum repolist for a long time interval...
Notes: here "a long time interval" means about a few days (at least more than 3 days),  but not a few hours ...
# 
# yum repolist                                                                    <<<  a few days interval
Loaded plugins: security, verify
Cluster                                                                                                                                    | 1.5 kB     00:00     
ClusterStorage                                                                                                                             | 1.5 kB     00:00     
RHEL_5.8_local                                                                                                                             |  951 B     00:00     
Server                                                                                                                                     | 1.5 kB     00:00     
VT                                                                                                                                         | 1.3 kB     00:00     
repo id                                                                               repo name                                                                                 status
Cluster                                                                               Cluster_r58                                                                                  32
ClusterStorage                                                                        ClusterStorage_r58                                                                           39
RHEL_5.8_local                                                                        RHEL_5.8_x86-64_all_local                                                                 3,414
Server                                                                                Server_r58                                                                                3,285
VT                                                                                    VT_r58                                                                                       58
repolist: 6,828
# 
# 
# yum repolist                                                                    <<<  a few hours interval
Loaded plugins: security, verify
repo id                                                                               repo name                                                                                 status
Cluster                                                                               Cluster_r58                                                                                  32
ClusterStorage                                                                        ClusterStorage_r58                                                                           39
RHEL_5.8_local                                                                        RHEL_5.8_x86-64_all_local                                                                 3,414
Server                                                                                Server_r58                                                                                3,285
VT                                                                                    VT_r58                                                                                       58
repolist: 6,828
# 


Update:

It would be really strange that my yum repo metadata lifetime is just default 3600 sec(s),
so here how to explain my yum repo metadata actual lifetime rather later than the default ? 
# yum -v repolist
Not loading "katello" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "product-id" plugin, as it is disabled
Not loading "rhnplugin" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "security" plugin
Not loading "subscription-manager" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "verify" plugin
Config time: 0.068
Yum Version: 3.2.22
Cluster                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                | 1.5 kB     00:00     
ClusterStorage                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | 1.5 kB     00:00     
Server                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | 1.5 kB     00:00     
VT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | 1.3 kB     00:00     
Setting up Package Sacks
pkgsack time: 0.032
Repo-id      : Cluster
Repo-name    : Cluster_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:38:19 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 32
Repo-size    : 83 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/Cluster/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Fri May 24 18:27:23 2024)

Repo-id      : ClusterStorage
Repo-name    : ClusterStorage_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:39:28 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 39
Repo-size    : 11 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/ClusterStorage/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Fri May 24 18:27:23 2024)

Repo-id      : RHEL_5.8_local
Repo-name    : RHEL_5.8_x86-64_all_local
Repo-updated : Tue Apr 23 10:43:03 2024
Repo-pkgs    : 3,414
Repo-size    : 3.6 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///install/rhel_5.8_x86-64_local
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Fri May 24 18:20:41 2024)

Repo-id      : Server
Repo-name    : Server_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:39:04 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 3,285
Repo-size    : 3.3 G
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/Server/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Fri May 24 18:27:23 2024)

Repo-id      : VT
Repo-name    : VT_r58
Repo-updated : Fri Feb  3 02:38:17 2012
Repo-pkgs    : 58
Repo-size    : 193 M
Repo-baseurl : file:///mnt/VT/
Repo-expire  : 3,600 second(s) (last: Fri May 24 18:27:23 2024)

repolist: 6,828
#


apologies if I'm misunderstanding you here!
yum downloads metadata regarding repos. after its done this the metadata is valid for a time period (have a look at man dnf.conf and metadata_expire)
if you run repolist within the valid period then the metadata wont be downloaded again, it will use the local metadata, else it will download new metadata.
you can view current status of repos with:
yum repolist enabled -v

